# Android App for Cars: Parking/Charging/Navigation

Tags: android-source, android-auto, android-automotive

I am trying to create Andriod Auto App for Parking and Charging. I found the guide from the link: https://developer.android.com/training/cars/navigation

It seems there are three categories of apps supported now in Android Automotive. But, only Media Service works for me, Parking, Charging or Navigation does not show up in the Android Auto app launcher. However, the Settings App show my installed App. The Supported App category listed below.

```
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService"/>
            <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.PARKING"/>
            <category android:name="aandroidx.car.app.category.CHARGING"/>
            <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.NAVIGATION"/>
```

The Emulator I am using is with Google Automotive System Image with Android 10.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, we have published / enabled only media app developers for Android Automotive OS (https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media/automotive-os).

We recently announced support for parking / nav / charging Android Auto (Projection) (eg. https://developer.android.com/training/cars/navigation).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try car_app_library [samples](https://github.com/android/car-samples) in Github? Esp. navigation module in it. I can see launcher icon for navigation sample in Polestar2 emulator by following README.md in the samples.

Comment: We have referred this samples, but i am unable to plot the real Google Map View in my Android Auto.  For More information refer this question.   

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70164411/android-auto-device-navigation-google-map-not-displayed