# Android Auto Device- Navigation Google Map Not displayed

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-auto, parking

We are working on **Android Auto device** support App for Navigation and Parking. As per Android Auto Development Guidelines and provided demo by Google [Android Auto car-samples](https://github.com/android/car-samples), we have implemented the same.

But when we are run the Application on DHU of Android Studio Google Map is not displayed, instead of that displayed the Static Image. FYI refer this screenshot.
[image: Android Auto Navigation Sceenshot - DHU]

Also We have referred [this solution of the stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67497050/android-auto-how-to-explicitly-open-google-map-for-navigation-to-show-on-car-s) but didn`t work for us

*Kindly help us the how to integrate or add Google Map Navigation in Android Auto*

Answer (score 0):

What kind of app are you trying to build - navigation Or parking/charging ?

Comment: We are looking for display the Charging stations and after click on Charging station shows the route using navigation in Android Auto Device